# iBeacon Proximity issue with iPhone 5S

Tags: ios7, cllocationmanager, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon

I am working on iBeacon app and it works fine for iPhone 5. I am checking if Proximity is 1, 2 or 3.  But with iPhone 5S even though beacon is far i am getting Proximity as 1 and rssi is mostly less than -60.

Has anyone else faced this issue, what is the difference in bluetooth for iPhone 5 and 5S?

Thanks

Comment: Can you reproduce this problem with a reference app like "Locate for iBeacon" or AirLocate?  What kind of beacons are you using?

Comment: I am using estimote beacons and i am able to create it with estimote app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So finally after spending a lot of time, i figured out that it's SDK bug in iOS 7.0.x if you have iPhone 5S. I installed iOS 7.1 Beta 5 in iPhone 5S and now proximity is not jumping randomly, its more accurate.

Comment: I am still seeing a fatal iBeacon issue with the iPhone 5S and iOS 7.1.0. Using startAdvertising with the 5S will work for about half a second and then stop advertising. Both AirLocate and my own app exhibit the issue. Every other device I have seems fine.

Comment: Thats weird, i have 5S and iOS 7.1 but don't have any issue like that.

Answer (score 0):

I found same issue, and then restart iPhone5S, problem solved.